# Getting Error.code = 0 in db.transaction function

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ripple

I am creating a project in Phonegap with Ionic.I am inserting and fetching dynamic content with sqlite and local storage.

I created a Dashboard contoller below are my dashboard controller code

```
angular.module('myWallet').controller('dashCtrl',  

function($scope,$state,$ionicPopup,$ionicHistory,AuthService){

 $scope.data = {};  

//goBack 
$scope.myGoBack = function() {
 $ionicHistory.goBack();
};

//********** error code function ************
function errorDashFunction(err)
{
   alert("Error Code: "+error.code);
}

//********** Success code function ************
function successDashFunction()
{
  var totalCashInHand = Coming_totalIncome - Coming_totalExpenses;
  alert(totalCashInHand );
}

var current_user_id=window.localStorage.getItem('userid');

var Coming_totalIncome = 0;
var Coming_totalExpenses= 0;
var Coming_totalCashInHand = 0;

//********** Fetching Values from DB ************
db.transaction(function (tx) { 

tx.executeSql("SELECT SUM(amount) as Totalincome FROM WALLET_INCOMES WHERE user_id ='"+current_user_id+"'", [], function(tx,results){
  console.log(results);

  if(results.rows[0].Totalincome != null)
  {
     Coming_totalIncome = results.rows[0].Totalincome;
  }

});

tx.executeSql("SELECT SUM(amount) as Totalexpenses FROM WALLET_EXPENSES WHERE user_id ='"+current_user_id+"'", [], function(tx,results){

   if(results.rows[0].Totalexpenses != null)
  {
  Coming_totalExpenses = results.rows[0].Totalexpenses;
  }

});

 return true;
},errorDashFunction,successDashFunction);


})
```

When i run this code on Ripple then it is alerting TotalCashInHand Price. 
BUT when i am running this code on my mobile then it is always showing Error code "0".